# How to pass strings from the parent model to a child's model's global variable in Netlogo's Levelspace

Tags: netlogo

I hope to receive some assistance on this problem.

I am trying to pass a string from the parent model to a child models global variable in Levelspace. When using ls:assign to accomplish this I receive the following error message;

" Extension exception: Model 0 encountered an error: Expected an anonymous command here, rather than a list or block."

I am at a loss on how to write the required anonymous command required to pass the string to the child model. Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Rudy

After creating the turtles (Kanban-Teams) in the parent model and calling their respective child models with "ls:create-interactive-models" I add the following code in setup:

```
ask Kanban-Teams [ 
if k-model-id = 0
   [
    ls:ask 0 [
      ls:assign capacity-input KanbanDev3
      setup ]
   ]
```

"capacity-input" is the child model global variable and "KanbanDev3" is the parent model global variable. I also used ls:let inplace of ls:assign and got the same results

Comment: Please post the code you wrote rather than just the name of the primitive.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are a couple ways to do what you want.

If you want to use `ls:assign` I think you do it [without an `ls:ask`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/ls.html#ls:assign), so maybe:

```
if k-model-id = 0 [
  ; no ask, just assign
  ls:assign 0 capacity-input KanbanDev3
]
```

The example from [the LevelSpace docs](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/ls.html#a-general-use-case-asking-and-reporting), just does an `ls:ask ls:models [ set grass? true ]`, where `grass?` is a global variable in the child mode.  So that's another option to try.

Comment: Thanks Jasper, that solved the problem. Much appreciated.